# Ocultar/Mostrar quando checkbox for marcado ou desmarcado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso verificar se um campo checkbox está marcado, e de acordo com seu estado, ocultar ou mostrar outro campo input, exemplo:

```
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" /> Clique aqui
    </label>
    <input type="optional" name="op1" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('[name="check"]').change(function() {
  $('[name="op1"]').toggle(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" /> Clique aqui
</label>
<input type="optional" name="op1" />
```

O script está monitorando o evento change dos elementos com o atributo `name="check"`, quando for alterado ele executa o evento `toggle` nos inputs com atributo `name="op1"`.

O `toggle` funciona da seguinte forma: Quando um `input` está oculto ele ficará visível, quando está visível, ele ficará oculto.

OBS.: O parâmetro 200 é um tempo em milissegundos que você quer que a ação aconteça, pra ele criar uma animação durante a transição, você pode modificar ou até retirar esse parâmetro, fica a seu critério.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz rapidão um código aqui, seria isso?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"  id="check" value="true"/> Clique aqui
    </label>
    <input type="optional" name="op1" id="opcao" />
<script>
    
    $("#check").click(function(){
 
  if($(this).val()=="true"){
   $("#opcao").css("visibility","hidden");
   $(this).val("false");
   }
   else{
     $("#opcao").css("visibility","visible");
     $(this).val("true");
    }
   
  
  });
    </script>
```