# Mostrar botão ao marcar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso que ao marcar o `checkbox` o botão de submit apareça. Porém como tenho mais que um `checkbox` ao clicar no segundo para marcar o botão some gostaria que continuasse aparecendo o botão até não ter nenhum checked.

Como posso adequar meu código abaixo para minha necessidade?

```
<form>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th></th>
   <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><input onclick="ocultar()" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input onclick="ocultar()" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input onclick="ocultar()" type="checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <button type="submit" class="tiny button" id="botao">
</form>

<script>
    function ocultar() {    
        if (document.getElementById("botao").style.display == "none") { 
            document.getElementById("botao").style.display = "block";    
        } else {
            document.getElementById("botao").style.display = "none";          
        }  
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#botao{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Posso criar uma versão do seu código usando `jquery` se quiser.

Comment: Se resolver pode ser sim.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ocultar/Mostrar quando checkbox for marcado ou desmarcado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170361/ocultar-mostrar-quando-checkbox-for-marcado-ou-desmarcado)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está chamando a função em todos os `checkbox` e apenas alternando o estado do botão a cada `click` nos checkboxs.

Realizei alguns reajustes em seu código, segue algum deles:

1- Coloquei um texto no botão para o mesmo ficar visível.

2- Adicionei um `id` ao botão para poder mudar o seu estado pelo script.

De resto, o código está todo comentado, caso possuir dúvidas me avise.

```js
//capturando evento de click e touch(mobile) em todos os checkboxs
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click touchstart', function(){
    //capturando a quantidade de checkboxs checados
    let quantCheck = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    
    /*verificando se o número de itens checados é diferente
     de zero para então mostrar o botão*/
    if(quantCheck != 0) {
        $('#botao').css('display', 'block')
    } 
    else {
        $('#botao').css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

```css
#botao{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th></th>
      <tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="tiny button" id="botao">
    Enviar
    </button>
</form>
```

**Obs:** Acrescentei o evento `touchstart` para dar suporte ao evento touch em telas sensíveis ao toque.

> Referência do evento
>   `touchstart`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events

Caso preferir um método usando apenas `vanillaJS`:

```js
//capturando todos os checkboxs
checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

//adicionando evento de click em todos os checkboxs
checks.forEach( function(ck){
    ck.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
        //pegando a quantidade de elementos checados
        let checked = document.querySelectorAll
        ('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        
        let botao = document.getElementById('botao');
        
        // se a quantidade de elementos checados for igual a 0, então esconde o botão
        if(checked == 0){
            botao.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            botao.style.display = "block";
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
#botao {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" /> <br> <br>

<button id="botao"> Botao!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu objetivo é exibir o botão apenas quando pelo menos um checkbox estiver marcado, você pode fazer isso apenas com javascript com o auxilio do método `querySelector()` com a query `"input[type=checkbox]:checked"`.

```js
function ocultar() {
  var marcados = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var botao = document.getElementById("botao");  
  botao.style.display = (marcados != null) ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input onclick="ocultar()" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input onclick="ocultar()" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input onclick="ocultar()" type="checkbox"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="tiny button" id="botao" style="display:none">Enviar</button>
</form>
```