# Saber se ao menos um checkbox está selecionado dentro de um array do laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Tenho um array do laravel que renderiza checkboxes:

```
@foreach($images as $img)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{url('gallery_images')}}/{{ $img->image }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
                <label class="check-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="excluir_todos[]" id="check-{{ $img->id }}" value="{{ $img->id }}"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
           <script src="{{ url('templates/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
            <script>
                $('#check-{{ $img->id }}').click(function() {
                    console.log($('#check-{{ $img->id }}').is(':checked'));
                    if($('#check-{{ $img->id }}').is(':checked')){
                        $('#btn-delete').removeClass('hide')
                    }else{
                        $('#btn-delete').addClass('hide')
                    }
                });
            </script> 
            @endforeach
```

Eu quero mostrar um botão apenas se ao menos um dos checkbox estiver selecionado. Da maneira que está acima, quando eu seleciono vários checkboxes, ele mostra o botão, mas quando eu desmarco apenas uma opção ele oculta o botão. Eu quero que ele oculte apenas quando todos os checkboxes foram desmarcados. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mostrar botão ao marcar checkbox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338922/mostrar-bot%c3%a3o-ao-marcar-checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz uma versão usando `vanillaJS`, basta pegar e adaptar ao seu código.

Todo o código está comentado, caso ainda houver duvidas, deixe nos comentários.

```js
//capturando todos os checkboxs
checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

//adicionando evento de click em todos os checkboxs
checks.forEach( function(ck){
    ck.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
        //pegando a quantidade de elementos checados
        let checked = document.querySelectorAll
        ('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        
        let botao = document.getElementById('botao');
        
        // se a quantidade de elementos checados for igual a 0, então esconde o botão
        if(checked == 0){
            botao.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            botao.style.display = "block";
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
#botao {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" /> <br> <br>

<button id="botao"> Botao!</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado, me serviu direitinho

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) que recebe uma função que será executada uma vez para cada elemento do array e retornará `true` apenas se todas as iterações da função retornarem `true`.

Como um objeto jQuery é um objeto [Array-Like](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#ArrayLikeObject), e não um Array propriamente dito, você pode usar o método [`jQuery.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) para convertê-lo e usar o método `every` mencionando acima.

Olha um exemplo funcionando.

```js
// Executa a busca no DOM apenas uma vez e salva a referência para melhor performance
var $checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
var $button = $('#btn');

$checkboxes
  .on('change', function() {
    // retorna true se todos os inputs tiverem `checked === false`
    var disable_button = $checkboxes.toArray().every(input => !input.checked );
    
    // Altera o estado do botão
    $button.prop('disabled', disable_button);
  })
  // executa o handler pra deixar o botão com o estado inicial válido
  .trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 4</label>

<hr>

<button id="btn" type="button">Ação</button>
```